# Parsing a comma separated 0 or more list using boost spirit x3

Tags: c++, parsing, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I often need to parse a comma separated `0 or more list` in boost spirit x3.
I know the `%-operator` which parses a `1 or more list` into an `std::vector`.
When I need a `0 or more list` I currently do it like this `-(element_parser % separator)`, which does what I want, but parses into a `boost::optional<std::vector>`, which is not quite the thing I am after.
So how can I make a parser, which parses a comma separated `0 or more list` into a plain std::vector using boost spirit x3.

Comment: The attribute is compatible. Try it. The compatibility/transformation rules are the winning point of the Spirit Libraries if you ask me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but using `-` works as expected for me:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

const x3::rule<class number_list_tag, std::vector<int>> integer_list = "integer_list";
const auto integer_list_def = -(x3::int_ % ',');
BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(integer_list);

template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    bool first = true;
    os << '[';
    for (const T& x : vec)
    {
        if (first)
            first = false;
        else
            os << ", ";

        os << x;
    }
    os << ']';
    return os;
}

std::vector<int> parse(const std::string& src)
{
    std::vector<int> result;
    auto iter = src.begin();
    bool success = x3::phrase_parse(iter, src.end(), integer_list, x3::space, result);
    if (!success || iter != src.end())
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to parse");
    else
        return result;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "\"\":\t" << parse("") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\"5\":\t" << parse("5") << std::endl;
    std::cout << "\"1, 2, 3\":\t" << parse("1, 2, 3") << std::endl;
}
```

Output is:

```
"":     []
"5":    [5]
"1, 2, 3":      [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: improved demo: https://godbolt.org/z/qKoW5Peob